# Import json in backbone View

Tags: javascript, json, backbone.js

I'm new to backbone, and I'm still getting used to the flow of everything.. What I'm trying to do is import `data.json` file in my Model and make use of it in my view...

data.json

```
[
  { id: "001", student: "Mark" },
  { id: "002", student: "Sally" },
  { id: "003", student: "Harold" }    
]
```

assets/data.js (model)

```
var DataModel = Backbone.Model.extend({
    url: 'assets/data.json',

    initialize: function() {
        // this logs properly
        console.log('this initializes');
    }
})
```

data_view.js

```
var Students = Backbone.View.extend({
    initialize: function() {
        var data = new DataModel();
        data.fetch();

        // doesn't return json
        console.log(data);
    }
})
```

data logs like so...

```
v __proto__: Backbone.Model
  > constructor: ()
  > initialize: ()
    url: "assets/data.json"
  > __proto__: Object
```

All of my imports are correct, but why isn't my json loading within my view? What am I doing wrong? (I've tried making a collection, but that had the same effect; no json to be found)

Comment: Is `data.json` inside assets? Are you using chrome? Do you have a web server? If not, Is local file access allowed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because fetch is using jQuery Ajax, so it's async. If you log data immediately after calling fetch, the data is not pull from server. You should do as follow:

```
data.fetch({
    success: function(model, response, options) {
        console.log(model);
    },
    error: function() {

    }
});
```

Link reference: http://backbonejs.org/#Model-fetch

Comment: I mean, if I log something in error(), it will log... :\

Comment: Can you provide the the error? And the data.json is static file?

Comment: `data.fetch({ success: function(model, response, options){console.log(data), error: function(){console.log('json was not found')}}})` I wonder if it's a parsing error?

Comment: And yes, it's a static json file

Answer (score 0):

With using JQuery:

```
        var DataModel = new DataModel();
        $.when(DataModel.fetch()).then(function() {
            var students = new Students({model: DataModel });
        });
```